# Can't start mysql in terminal for OSX 10.8 with standard XAMPP stack installation

Tags: mysql, macos, client, osx-lion

**Error**
sql: command not found

**.profile code** 
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH

I've edited the filed saved it and tried multiple versions and unable to get mysql to start

Answer (score 0):

Type `whereis sql` and put whatever it prints into your PATH, minus the program name. e.g, if it prints `usr/bin/sql`, then makes sure `/usr/bin` is in your PATH.

Comment: SevenBits when I type in whereis sql it say command not found

Answer (score 0):

To start mysql, you type `mysql` not `sql`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there somethign wrong with the .profile code I am saving to the user? export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH